# How to build apps in subfolders with Makefile

Tags: makefile, directory

I'm trying to write a Makefile that will build apps stored in subfolders. So structure of the folders is as follows:

```
examples/
    Makefile
    hello_world/ 
        file1.c
        main.c
        **hello_world** <- expected build result

    example1/
        otherfile.c
        main.c
        **example1** <- expected build result

    example2/
        main.c
        ...
        **example2** <- expected build result
```

My Makefile (simplified) looks like this:

```
EXAMPLES := hello_world example1 example2

SRC = $(wildcard */*.c)
OBJ = ${SRC:.c=.o}
OUT = $(foreach e, $(EXAMPLES), $(addprefix $(e)/,$(e)) )

CC := gcc

all: examples

$(OBJ): $(SRC)
    @$(CC)  -c $< -o $@
    
$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(filter $(dir $@)%,$^) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    @rm -f $(OUT) $(OBJ)
```

Is there a way to make it work? Or maybe I should have Makefile in each folder separately?

This rule seems to solve my problem, matches outputs to .o, but filters files that are passed for linking with filter function

```
$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(filter $(dir $@)%,$^) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

Replaced old rule:

```
$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

with

```
examples: $(OBJ)
    $(foreach e, $(EXAMPLES),                               \
        $(CC) $(wildcard $(e)/*.o) -o $(e)/$(e) $(LDFLAGS); \
    )
```

*almost* works now, after clean, the compilation works as expected, only linking fails ($(wildcard $(e)/*.o) is empty?), after second run examples are created as expected

Comment: Yes, there is a way to make it work. (More than one, actually.) A good first step: when you write a line like `SRC = $(wildcard $(EXAMPLES)/*.c)`, the next line should be `$(info SRC contains $(SRC))`, just until you verify that your assignment did what you intended.

Comment: @Beta made some progress (updated question) don't know why first linking fails :(

Comment: When writing rules for makefiles it's important to think about one rule creating one target.  Don't try to write rules that make lots of targets.  That's almost always going to turn out badly.

Comment: Hmm I think I found the solution... map out to .o but limit what is linked by a folder containing the given example...

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer in the answer space below

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by comments by [Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955715/how-to-build-apps-in-subfolders-with-makefile/69957456#comment123662792_69955715) and [MadScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69955715/how-to-build-apps-in-subfolders-with-makefile/69957456#comment123663245_69955715), I think I have a solution:

```
EXAMPLES := hello_world example1 example2

SRC = $(wildcard */*.c)
OBJ = ${SRC:.c=.o}
OUT = $(foreach e, $(EXAMPLES), $(addprefix $(e)/,$(e)) )

CC := gcc

all: $(OUT)

%.o: %.c
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    
$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    @$(CC) $(filter $(dir $@)%,$^) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    @rm -f $(OUT) $(OBJ)

.PHONY: all clean
```